# Accuracy issue with document.scrollingElement.scrollTop on mobile with a sticky and shrinking effect

Tags: javascript, css

I use `document.scrollingElement.scrollTop` in order to get the position of the user on the page to trigger a sticky shrinking header. It works well on desktop, but on mobile, when reaching the condition ( `if (yPosition > 50)` ), it won't work nicely. The header will 'vibrate' (shrink and then reset to normal multiple times in a few seconds). I used `console.log` on the `yPosition` and noticed this was because on mobile, the value was, when the issue occurs, switching between 48-54 and thus triggering the issue I described above.

I guess the issue is because of the way the elements are shrinking, if I remove the shrinking effect, then I don't have the issue anymore. I'd like to preserve the shrinking effect and find a way to remove this issue on mobile. Any hints?

Please see this gif for a visual representation of my issue:
https://i.imgur.com/pxLVBge.mp4

Here is my code, I deleted the parts that I considered unnecessary for the demonstration of my issue.

```js
const navMenu = (() => {
    const header = document.getElementById("header");
    const menu = document.getElementById("hamburger");


    const display = () => {
        menu.addEventListener('click', _defaultMenu);
    }

    const _defaultMenu = () => {
        menu.classList.toggle("active");
        if (menu.classList.contains("active")) {
            bodyScrollLock.disableBodyScroll(document.querySelector("body"));
        } else {
            bodyScrollLock.enableBodyScroll(document.querySelector("body"));
        }
    }

    const _shrinkMenu = () => {
        menu.classList.toggle("activeShrunk");
        if (menu.classList.contains("activeShrunk")) {
            bodyScrollLock.disableBodyScroll(document.querySelector("body"));
        } else {
            bodyScrollLock.enableBodyScroll(document.querySelector("body"));
        }
    }

    const stickyEffect = () => {
        document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
            let yPosition = document.scrollingElement.scrollTop;
            console.log(yPosition);
            if (yPosition > 50) {
                menu.removeEventListener('click', _defaultMenu);
                menu.addEventListener('click', _shrinkMenu);
            }
            else {
                menu.removeEventListener('click', _shrinkMenu);
                menu.addEventListener('click', _defaultMenu);
            }
        })
    }

    return { display, stickyEffect };
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just solved my issue. I switched from `sticky` to `fixed` and now it works perfectly on mobile. I think this is related to how `sticky` works.